# Generate a random, fixed length password in PHP that comply to a password policy

Tags: php, random, passwords

I need to generate a random password containing 8 characters. The password must comply to below policy --

A Password should

- contain a minimum of one (1) non-alphabetic character
- not contain more than two (2) consecutive repeated characters

I am generating my password using below function.

```
function random_pass() {
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '' ;
    while ($i <= 7) {
        $num = rand() % 60;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

And I have written below validation function that checks if the generated password is according to password policy

```
function password_policy($string)
{
    // contains a minimum of one (1) non-alphabetic character
    $r1 = '/[^a-zA-Z]+/';
    // contains more than two (2) consecutive repeated characters
    $r2 = '/(.)\\1{2}/';

    if (preg_match_all($r1,$string, $o)<1) {
        return "invalid - all alphabetic";
    }
    if (!preg_match_all($r2,$string, $o)<1) {
        return "invalid - more than 2 consecutive repeated chars";
    }
    return "valid";
}
```

My `random_pass` doesn't work accurately all the time. Out 5-10 times out of 100, my password fails to comply with the password policy.

```
for ($j=0;$j<100;$j++) {
    $pass = random_pass();
    $validation = password_policy($pass);
    if ($validation !== 'valid') {
        print_r("$pass -- $validation\n");
    }
}
```

-- output --

```
BCZHDgKl -- invalid - all alphabetic
xfCKKKH3 -- invalid - more than 2 consecutive repeated chars
aMtcWqEx -- invalid - all alphabetic
ZtpDGeKU -- invalid - all alphabetic
```

How do I generate such password that will 100% comply to aforementioned policy.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple no-brainer approach - just skip invalid passwords and move on to the next until you've generated 100 valid ones.

Comment: Well, you just have to keep generating it until it passes your test... the impact on performance would be acceptable I guess. If it only fails 5/10 % of the time it means chances are big that you're already ok on first iteration, and most probably after second if the first one fails...

Comment: I don't want 100 valid passwords. I want a random_password generation function that will surely generate a valid password.

Comment: @Hussain: have a loop in your generator like: `do { pass=generate } while(!valid(pass))`

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be: in your random_pass() function in a loop check if the generated password satisfies the policies. If not, generate a new one until you get a correct one and then return it.

Comment: Note: 1. In actual scenario there is no for loop. I have written a for loop to show inaccuracy of the random_pass function. 2. Validating password after generating it will slow me down.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
function random_pass() {
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '' ;
    while ($i <= 7) {
        $num = rand() % 60;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }
    $valid=password_policy($pass);
    if($valid=="valid")
       return $pass;
    else return random_pass();
}
```

Comment: So there is no other way then??

Comment: Yes. because password policy is a logic you create to tell the machine